# How to set global process variables in Camunda-BPM?

Tags: java, variables, scope, bpmn, camunda

I have a simple bpmn process
in which i am using 2 service task,I am executing my process by using
`processEngine.getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("Process_1", variables);`
where my variables is as follows:

```
Map variables = new HashMap();
variables.put("a", 2);
variables.put("b", 5);
```

Service task 1 implements an `Addition` java class and service task 2 implements a `Multiplication` class.

Now I want to have 3 variables (constants)  `c = 5`, `d = 10`, `e = 2` so that I can use `c` for service task 1 such that in `Addition` I can use this variable, similarly I want to use `d` in my `Multiplication` class, and `e` should be global so that I can use it in both classes.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a quick fix you could include a Setup-Service Task as the first Task of the process which prefills your process-variables. 
Depending on how you start a process you could either:
Set the Variables via the java-object-api

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/variables/#java-object-api

or you if you use a REST call you can provide these fixed values within the request body:

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/reference/rest/process-definition/post-start-process-instance/

Another simple solution would be a class with static values or a enum holding the needed values.

--edit--

if you want to use the inputOutput extension add something like this to your bpmn file:

```
<bpmn:process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
  <bpmn:extensionElements>
    <camunda:inputOutput>
      <camunda:inputParameter name="c">5</camunda:inputParameter>
      <camunda:inputParameter name="d">10</camunda:inputParameter>
      <camunda:inputParameter name="e">2</camunda:inputParameter>
    </camunda:inputOutput>
  </bpmn:extensionElements>
```

this can't be done in the diagram view of the camunda modeler, just switch to the XML representation of the process and add the extensionElement.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your information.I was thinking about attaching some execution listener with these service tasks.Can we do by using Execution listner? One more thing i want to ask is we have some input/output and properties in camunda modeler,what is the use of that and how to use them?

Comment: I truly appreciate your time and effort.I was thinking of defining these variables in my camunda modeler(i.e inside process model itself)
In camunda modeler with service task we can attach some input/output and in extension we can have some properties also.My question is can we define our process variables there,if not then where and how can we use them?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows two different ways to store the value:

Java object api
Typed value api

I think using Java object api requires the java object to implement serializable interface? The following code would break, if Order object does not implement Serializable interface

```
com.example.Order order = new com.example.Order();
runtimeService.setVariable(execution.getId(), "order", order);

com.example.Order retrievedOrder = (com.example.Order) runtimeService.getVariable(execution.getId(), "order");
```

==

I would use the following format for java object

```
ObjectValue customerDataValue = Variables.objectValue(customerData)
  .serializationDataFormat(Variables.SerializationDataFormats.JAVA)
  .create();

execution.setVariable("someVariable", customerDataValue);
```

customerdata refers to any java object. However if there member variables contains some other references, those references needs to serializable as well. To avoid this you will have declare those references as transient

Further more, use setVariableLocal method if you dont want the data to be persisted in DB

Comment: what is execution and how do i get Instance of it?

Comment: execution is a context variable

Answer (score 0):

**To create variable as gloable:**`org.camunda.bpm.engine.variable.Variables.putValue("keyName", VariableType);`

**To get global varibale:** `VariableType value = (VariableType) delegateExecution.getVariable("getKey");`

**Note:** Your dto has to be serializable otherwise it camnuda will throw serialization error.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, .getVariable() will get the variables from the current ProcessInstance.